# Installing wheel packages in Windows

Tags: python, pip, package, python-wheel

I was trying to install some extra packages I got from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) to my Python IDE. I never used this kind of extension `.whl`. I also read an article with some possible solutions, but nothing works. I followed this:

I just used the following which was quite simple:

> First open a console and use `pip` to install `wheel`
>
> ```
> pip install wheel
> ```
>
> then `cd` to where you've downloaded your file like `some-package.whl`
>   and use
>
> ```
> pip install some-package.whl
> ```

But the only thing I got was:

[image: pip prompt]

Any idea what I should do?

Comment: Well *are* you using a `win32` platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah, I just figured out that a number in the name of the wheel file refers to the Python version I'm trying to add a package. So the only thing I had to do was change `scikit_image-0.11.3-cp**34**-none-win_amd64.whl` to `scikit_image-0.11.3-cp**27**-none-win_amd64.whl`.

Thanks for the help!

See ya!

Answer (score 1):

You might have a 64 bit system where you are trying to install a 32 bit package. Use the version that says 64 or amd64 instead.

Comment: I'm using a 64 bits platform. I've just downloaded a 64 bit package, but I'm still getting the same message.